# Python - Switch/Case using a Dictionnary implies the interpretation of each case

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement

In the aim of emulating a `switch/case` block using a `dictionary`, I noticed something that isn't really supposed to occur:

```
print {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2 + '',
    'c': 3,
}['a']
```

I'm expecting that, since the key given is `'a'` => the second line (key `b`) shouldn't be interpreted.

But what I get is:

```
'b': 2 + '',
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Which means that the second line has been interpreted anyway.

Somebody has an explanation to this phenomenon?
Or another way to emulate a switch without implying that `python` interprets each `case`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't use lazy evaluation, so it has to create the entire dictionary before you can access an element of it with `['a']`. If any part of the dictionary creation gets an error, you fail at that part.

If you want to emulate `switch/case`, including the fact that it doesn't execute the bodies of the unselected cases, you can put functions into the dictionary.

```
print {
    'a': lambda: 1,
    'b': lambda: 2 + '',
    'c': lambda: 3
}['a']()
```

For more info about this, see

[Why Doesn't Python Have Switch/Case?](http://www.pydanny.com/why-doesnt-python-have-switch-case.html)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I wonder why using `functions` as `dictionnary values` does not make `python` interpret each entry of the dictionary.

Comment: Because functions are not interpreted until they're called. Otherwise, merely defining the function `launch_nukes` would cause a catastrophe.

Answer (score 1):

While you may be trying to emulate a `switch` statement, this is not a `switch` statement. In your code, the entire dictionary is created before you pick out the value at key `'a'`. So, if there's an error anywhere in the dictionary, you're going to get an error, before it ever gets to the point of picking out `'a'`.

Here's a good way to emulate a `switch` in Python:

```
choice = 'a'  # From user input or somewhere else

if choice == 'a':
    result = 1
elif choice == 'b':
    result = 2 + ''  # I kept the error for demonstration
elif choice == 'c':
    result = 3

print result
```

This will print `1` without executing the other blocks, including the one with the error.

You could also just `print` directly in the `if`/`elif` blocks, without assigning to a variable first.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is a value; its literal will evaluate all subexpressions to construct the dictionary. Thus, everything in `{ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 + '', 'c': 3 }` is evaluated before `['a']` can be invoked on it, and only then can `print` take it as argument. A dictionary is not an execution flow control mechanism, and can't shortcut like boolean operators, `if` and `switch` do.

Answer (score 1):

Before you take key `a` from the anonymous dict, the dict is already init. When it init, you get the TypeError above.